# To open the popUp menu through Tab button

Tags: macos, cocoa, popupmenu

I want to open the popUp menu through the TAB button. Attaching an image to explain it.

[image]

When I press TAB on the first textField it should open the popUp menu below it and so on. Currently it just selects the popUp menu and we have to click on it to open.

Please let me know if there is a way to open the popUp menu through TAB.

Thanks